# How to append code to a section?

Tags: spacing, sectioning, sections-paragraphs, etoolbox, patching

In my `scrartcl` document I want to change the spacing between sections and the first paragraph. Since I am using the `parskip` package, the parskip is set to a non-zero value. The `\section` command uses `\parskip` as well, but I want to remove that.

This could be achieved with the following code:

```
\section{Introduction}
\vskip-\parskip
```

This works perfectly fine. How can I append that code to the `\section` command in LaTeX without redefining all the rest? There is the [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/etoolbox/) with commands like `\appto`, but applying it as follows results only into errors:

```
\appto{\section}{\vskip-\parskip}
```

I guess because `\section` takes arguments, what would be right command or is there an alternative solution?

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? And what about `\subsection`s and other sectional units?

Comment: @Werner Thanks for pointing out. I am using the `scrartcl` document class and for other sectional units I would simply replicate the command.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not because of `\section` taking an argument (or multiple arguments) *per se*. It's because `\section` acts as an intermediate function before processing the arguments following it. In fact, in the standard document classes `\section` takes no arguments at all (from [`article.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls), but similar for [`scrartcl.cls`](http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script)):

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
```

As such, *appending* code to `\section` actually *inserts* it between functions that expect certain arguments which, as you've found out, causes problems. So, while `\@startsection` is defined to take 6 arguments and does above, it's actually `\@sect` (for numbered) and `\@ssect` (for unnumbered or starred) that sets the sectional title. Even further "down the line", `\@xsect` is called to set the after-heading functionality, so I've patched that below:

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}% http://ctan.org/pkg/koma-script
\usepackage{parskip}% http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}% Original untouched \section
Here is some text.

\section{Introduction}% \section with manual modification
\vskip-\parskip
Here is some text.

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@xsect}% <cmd>
  {\ignorespaces}% <search>
  {\vskip-\parskip\relax\ignorespaces}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother

\section{Introduction}% Modified \section after patch
Here is some text.
\end{document}
```

Since this modification is done on a macro called by *all* sectioning units, it will hold for all.

Comment: Interesting explanation about the *sectioning* process used by `LaTeX`, i read the [`source2e.pdf`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/base/source2e.pdf) (page 285) but i didn't understand until i read this answer.

Answer (score 1):

In `scrartcl.cls` you will find the following definition.

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
  {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
  {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
  {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
    \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi 
    \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
```

The second and third lines determine the size of the space before and after a section heading, respectively. You could use `\patchcmd` from the [etoolbox package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), or you could redefine the `\section` directly. Either way, you need `\makeatletter` because the code contains `@` symbols.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{1pt}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Some text
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\section{\@startsection{section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {1pt}%
      {\ifnum \scr@compatibility>\@nameuse{scr@v@2.96}\relax
        \setlength{\parfillskip}{\z@ plus 1fil}\fi 
        \raggedsection\normalfont\sectfont\nobreak\size@section}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{A section}
Some text
\section{Another section}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, but why should I choose `\renewcommand` over `\patchcmd` here?

Comment: @platzhirsch --- No particular reason. I only use etoolbox in this way if I want to patch a very long definition, but that's just my personal preference.

Comment: What I don't understand is how `parskip` affects the space after a section heading. It seems these are only semi-fixed values: `-2.3ex` and `.2ex`. Anyway, could you add the complete `patchcmd` to your answer for completeness? I am having troubles with it: `\patchcmd{\section}{2.3ex \@plus.2ex}{1pt}{}{false}` does not work.

Comment: `\par` crops up in lots of places, including in the definition of `\@startsection`. Changing `\parskip` can have nasty side effects.

Comment: Maybe I should go back to using `\vskip 2ex` then every time I want a paragraph. Just didn't seem convenient for a clean solution.