# How to get a flexible left margin in the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, margins, titletoc

I'm aware that using package `titletoc` one can easily change the format of ToC. But, I'm wondering if there exist some solutions to make the left margin in ToC flexible. By "flexible", I mean that the left margin of certian level will change according to the current label number. For example, if there exist a \chapter, but no \section, \subsection and \subsubsection, then an immediate \paragraph will have the same margin in TC as the normal \section. I know that the margin of a section title is basically controlled by the `<left>` option in `titletoc` package. So my naive idea is to combine this with some `\ifthenelse`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xifthen}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\newlength{\TOCparagraphskip}
\setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{9em}

\titlecontents*
    {paragraph}
    [\ifnum\pdfmatch{.[.].[.].[.]0[.].}{\thecontentslabel}=1
        \setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{7em}%
        \ifnum\pdfmatch{.[.].[.]0[.]0[.].}{\thecontentslabel}=1
            \setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{3.8em}%
            \ifnum\pdfmatch{.[.]0[.]0[.]0[.].}{\thecontentslabel}=1
                \setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{1.5em}%
                \ifnum\pdfmatch{0[.]0[.]0[.]0[.].}{\thecontentslabel}=1
                    \setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{0em}%
                \fi
            \fi
        \fi
    \else
        \setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{9em}%
    \fi    
    \TOCparagraphskip]{}{\textbullet{}\;}{}{}[\quad]



\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \paragraph{paragraph}


    \chapter{chapter one}

   
\end{document}
```

But, unfortunately, my naive try give error message.

```
 (./test.toc
./test.toc:1: Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.1 ...aph}{\numberline {0.0.0.0.1}paragraph}{1}{}
                                                  %
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

./test.toc:1: Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.1 ...aph}{\numberline {0.0.0.0.1}paragraph}{1}{}
                                                  %
Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)


./test.toc:1: Package calc Error: `\let ' invalid at this point.

See the calc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1 ...aph}{\numberline {0.0.0.0.1}paragraph}{1}{}
                                                  %
I expected to see one of: + - * / )
```

But I've checked that with or without my personal hack, the `.toc` file are in fact the same.

```
\contentsline {paragraph}{\numberline {0.0.0.0.1}paragraph}{1}{}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}chapter one}{3}{}%
\contentsfinish
```

So, I don't know where is the problem. Or, maybe someone else has some better idea to implement this functionality?

Comment: The `tocloft` package is also designed for controlling the appearance of the ToC, etc.

Comment: I have no idea why you would want to follow a `\chapter` by a `\paragraph` with no intermediate divisions. As a reader I would find that very confusing.

Comment: @PeterWilson So, the structure of my note is as follows. Basically I will arrange my note into different down-to-the-earth topics, for example, maybe the first topic will be a summarization of a paper and the second will be one of my thoughts got during my bath. I will continuously enlarge and rearrange every topics during my study. In LaTeX file, every topic is a paragraph. Then, I will group my topics. But, this grouping is not bottom-to-up, but up-to-bottom to comply with the structure of a LaTeX file.

Comment: That is to say, if I want to group two topics, then the first thing I will do is to create a chapter (I don't like part so I don't use it), then if subdivision is needed, I will create sections and so on. So, it is often the case that my chapter will govern only many paragraph, but with no section since I find subdivision is not needed. For example when there are only two topics (paragraph), then I hardly find no cause to create sections.

Comment: "In LaTeX file, every topic is a paragraph" this means that I use paragraphs to identify topics in the LaTeX file. I will also use some specific formatting style to make readers (actually, usually I'm the only reader of my note) know that ok this is a topic and this is a new topic. To summarize, basically my note is consisted of many paragraphs (topics), and only when needed, I will then try to group them into chapters, sections, and so on.

Comment: Also, I know the existence of your package tocloft. But since I first encounter titletoc and titlesec so I first try to realize my thought in this package in order for immediate use. I will definitely try to learn more about tocloft in the future since I hear that it is more powerful than titletoc concerning the user-alternation of the ToC.

Comment: As an off-topic comment: I've tried doing a personal journal like this before, and the static PDF output is really, really not searchable. If the consumer of the output is just yourself, I would actually suggest using a brain-mapping of knowledge management software like [Notion](https://notion.so) or [Roam](https://roamresearch.com).

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks! I will definitely check the two software that you talk about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would implement what you want instead.

Basic example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\newlength{\TOCparagraphskip}
\setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{9em}

\titlecontents*
    {paragraph}
    [\TOCparagraphskip]{}{\textbullet{}\;}{}{}[\quad]



\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \paragraph{paragraph}

    \chapter{chapter one}
    \addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{1em}}

    \paragraph{paragraph 2}
   
\end{document}
```

You see that but inserting various `\setlength` into the toc file you can change the left indent on the fly.

Now let's try to automate it. Unfortunately the `<after code>` in `titlesec` doesn't work because it results in the contents line being printed too early. However, trying to use `etoolbox` to append code to run *after* sectioning commands [is prone to unexpected errors](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75184/how-to-append-code-to-a-section).

In the solution below, what we do is the following:

- We patch the `\paragraph` command so that *before* the normal `\paragraph` is called, we check to see if the indentation needs changing. If it does, then we issue an `\addtocontents` to do so.
- The checking is done with a boolean toggle that we defined. After we issue the `\addtocontents`, we reset the toggle.
- Patching *before* the command is less problematic, since you don't have to worry about `*` forms or other shenanigans. I did it by hand below, but I think using the `\pretocmd` macro from `etoolbox` would work just as well.
- We patch each sectioning command (`\chapter`, `\section`, `\subsection`, and so on; I got tired of typing so you have to add the additional levels yourself) to indicate that the indentation level has changed, and store the appropriate lengths.
- The sectioning commands now set the boolean toggle to true, and then store the appropriate lengths so that when `\paragraph` is called the right length is placed in the `.toc` file.
- The boolean toggle is not strictly necessary: it helps keep the size of the `.toc` file down (otherwise you print one `\setlength` command for each `\paragraph`). In the example below it would be 7 times without the toggle, and 5 times with the toggle.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\newlength{\TOCparagraphskip}
\setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{9em}


\titlecontents*
    {paragraph}
    [\TOCparagraphskip]{}{\textbullet{}\;}{}{}[\quad]

\makeatletter
\newif\ifqt@tocskipchanged
\qt@tocskipchangedfalse

% Some helper macros to simplify typing
\newcommand\qt@tocchangepskip[1]{\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{#1}}}

% Patch the sectioning commands
\let\qt@chap\chapter
\def\chapter{\qt@tocskipchangedtrue\gdef\qt@prepare{\qt@tocchangepskip{1.5em}}\qt@chap}
\let\qt@sec\section
\def\section{\qt@tocskipchangedtrue\gdef\qt@prepare{\qt@tocchangepskip{4em}}\qt@sec}
\let\qt@ssec\subsection
\def\subsection{\qt@tocskipchangedtrue\gdef\qt@prepare{\qt@tocchangepskip{7em}}\qt@ssec}
%% insert additional definitions here for subsubsections etc.
% Patch the paragraph command
\let\qt@para\paragraph
\def\paragraph{\ifqt@tocskipchanged\qt@prepare\fi\qt@tocskipchangedfalse\qt@para}
% In case there are paragraphs outside of traditional chapters. Call this after \tableofcontents
\def\setdefaultparaskip{\qt@tocskipchangedtrue\gdef\qt@prepare{\qt@tocchangepskip{0em}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \tableofcontents

    \setdefaultparaskip % Only necessary if there is a paragraph before any chapters
    \paragraph{paragraph}

    \chapter{chapter one} 
    \paragraph{paragraph 2}

    \section{Section one}

    \paragraph{paragraph 3}
    
    \section{Section two}

    \paragraph{paragraph 4}

    \paragraph{paragraph 4.5}

    \paragraph{paragraph 4.6}

    \chapter{chapter two}
    \paragraph{paragraph 5}
  
\end{document}
```

The output TOC from the code above:

[image]

Comment: Brilliant! Yesterday I was stuck with the idea of implementing this redefinition at the beginning of \paragraph, but your idea is surely more elegant!

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion of adding `\addtocontents{toc}{\setlength{\TOCparagraphskip}{1em}}` to the `<after code>` of `\titleformat`. But this does not fix the problem. It seems that now every paragraph item in ToC is typeset as if it all follows a `\chapter` command. I suspect that this is because ToC itself come with a `\chapter` command. I also get this suspect form the fact that the `\titleformat`'s `<after code>` version will get an additional line `\TOCparagraphskip 1.5em\relax` in the beginning of `toc` file if `1.5em` is the skip I set after `\chapter`.

Comment: You are right that it didn't work, but that has to do with the order in which the commands were written to the `.toc` file. Let me see if I can hack a workaround.

Comment: @QiTianluo: updated. Instead of using `titlesec` I just did the length setting by hand in this version.

Comment: Thank you very much! I find your answer very helpful!

Comment: But I do not quite understand what you mean by "but that has to do with the order in which the commands were written to the `.toc` file". Care to elaborate on it a little bit?

Comment: If you try to put the `\addcontents` command to the `<after code>`, you see in the `.toc` file that the line to set `\TOCparagraphskip` appears _before_ the corresponding line for the chapter/section etc; whereas in the example above you will find that in the `.toc` file the two lines are reversed. I haven't looked at exactly how `titletoc` hooks into the internals to change the lengths, but evidently this makes a difference.

Comment: Get it. Thanks!